# Application Insights not showing logs in Azure Portal

Tags: c#, .net, azure

I'm logging into Azure App Insights, I can see the logs in the Output window of visual studio, but do not see any logs in the App Insights.

My Log File

```
<nlog xmlns="http://www.nlog-project.org/schemas/NLog.xsd"
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.nlog-project.org/schemas/NLog.xsd NLog.xsd"
      autoReload="true"
      throwExceptions="false"
      internalLogLevel="Off" internalLogFile="c:\temp\nlog-internal.log">

    <extensions>
        <add assembly="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.NLogTarget"/>
    </extensions>
    <targets>
        <target name="aiTarget" xsi:type="ApplicationInsightsTarget" >
            <instrumentationKey>MyKey</instrumentationKey>
            <!-- Only required if not using ApplicationInsights.config -->
            <contextproperty name="threadid" layout="${threadid}" />
            <!-- Can be repeated with more context -->
        </target>
    </targets>

    <rules>
        <logger name="*" minlevel="Info" writeTo="aiTarget" />
    </rules>
</nlog>
```

Source Code :

```
private static readonly NLog.Logger Logger = NLog.LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger();
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string inputFolderPath = @"C:\ProjectArea\5471\OutputDir";
            string projectName = "5471_2021";
            string outputFilePath = @"C:\ProjectArea\5471";

            string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(inputFolderPath);

            foreach (string file in files)
            {
                Logger.Info("Hello world");
                Logger.Trace("This should go to App insight");
                Console.WriteLine("Processed file : " + file);
            }
        }
```

Tried adding Nlog config in app.config. Even after an hour I do not see the logs.

Comment: can you provide .net version which you have used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried your code with minor changes and successfully observed logs in Application Insights.

**nlog.config**:

```xml
<nlog xmlns="http://www.nlog-project.org/schemas/NLog.xsd"
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.nlog-project.org/schemas/NLog.xsd NLog.xsd"
      autoReload="true"
      throwExceptions="false"
      internalLogLevel="Off" internalLogFile="c:\temp\nlog-internal.log">
    <extensions>
        <add assembly="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.NLogTarget"/>
    </extensions>
    <targets>
        <target name="aiTarget" xsi:type="ApplicationInsightsTarget" >
            <instrumentationKey>InstrumentationKey</instrumentationKey>
            <!-- Only required if not using ApplicationInsights.config -->
            <contextproperty name="threadid" layout="${threadid}" />
            <!-- Can be repeated with more context -->
        </target>
    </targets>
    <rules>
        <logger name="*" minlevel="Info" writeTo="aiTarget" />
    </rules>
</nlog>
```

I added the following line in Program.cs:

`TelemetryConfiguration.Active.InstrumentationKey = instrumentationKey;`.

**Program.cs**:

```cs
using System;
using System.IO;
using Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Extensibility;
using NLog;

class Program
{
    private static readonly Logger Logger = LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger();

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        try
        {
            string instrumentationKey = "InstrumentationKey";
            TelemetryConfiguration.Active.InstrumentationKey = instrumentationKey;
            Console.WriteLine($"Instrumentation Key: {instrumentationKey}");
            Console.WriteLine("Initializing NLog...");
            NLog.LogManager.LoadConfiguration("nlog.config");          
            string inputFolderPath = @"C:<filepath>";
            string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(inputFolderPath);
            foreach (string file in files)
            {
                Logger.Info("Hello world");
                Logger.Trace("This should go to App insight");
                Console.WriteLine("Processed file: " + file);
            }
            Console.WriteLine("Logs sent successfully.");        
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            // Log any unhandled exceptions
            Logger.Error(ex, "Unhandled exception occurred");
            Console.WriteLine($"Error: {ex.Message}");

            // Keep the console window open to review errors
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
        finally
        {
            LogManager.Shutdown();
        }
    }
}
```

**.csproj**:

```xml
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.NLogTarget" Version="2.22.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="NLog" Version="5.2.8" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <None Update="nlog.config">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </None>
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

This is my Console Output.

**Output**:

[image]

**Local Logger Trace**:

[image]

**App Insights Logger Trace**:

[image]